# Javascript Array loses content when passed to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Oops, it seems I was mistaken. As @MDeSchaepmeester & @charlietfl point out it should work, and I see now it does. The problem is now it is not rendering the DataTable.

Any suggestions as to why it does not load into DataTables with no error are welcome!!

Here's all the code as requested:

```
function PartnerListSupportTickets() {

    jQuery("#loader").show();

    var idOpen = 'tickets-tbl-open';
    var idOnHold = 'tickets-tbl-on-hold';
    var idDeferred = 'tickets-tbl-deferred';
    var idClosed = 'tickets-tbl-closed';
    var tblDataOpen = [];
    var tblDataOnHold = [];
    var tblDataDeferred = [];
    var tblDataClosed = [];
    var tblEmptyMsg = [];

    tblEmptyMsg.push({
        ticket: 'No tickets available for this category',
        postcode: '-',
        state: '-',
        customer: '-',
        status: '-',
        priority: '-',
        fault: '-',
        category: '-',
        author: '-',
        owner: '-',
        age: '-',
        lastupdate: '-'
    });

    var get_data_url = '/sma-php/gettickets.php?var=PARTCK&pid=' + sessionStorage.party_id;

    jQuery.getJSON( get_data_url, function( data ) {

        OpenNum = 0;
        OnHoldNum = 0;
        DeferredNum = 0;
        ClosedNum = 0;

        jQuery.each( data, function( i, d ) {

            var status = d.status;
            status = status.toLowerCase(); 

            if(status == 'closed') {
                var now = moment();
                var then = moment(d.create_date);
                d.days_age = now.diff(then, 'days');
            };

            switch(status) {
                case('open'):
                    OpenNum = OpenNum + 1;
                    tblDataOpen.push({
                        ticket: '<span id="' + d.ticket_id + '" class="ticket-id-class">' + d.short_title + '</span>',
                        postcode: d.postcode,
                        state: d.state,
                        customer: d.customer_name,
                        status: d.status,
                        priority: '<font color="' + d.color + '">' + d.priority + '</font>',
                        fault: d.fault_type,
                        category: d.category,
                        author: d.author_name,
                        owner: d.owner_name,
                        age: d.days_age,
                        lastupdate: d.update_date
                    });
                break;

                case('on hold'):
                    OnHoldNum = OnHoldNum + 1;
                    tblDataOnHold.push({
                        ticket: '<span id="' + d.ticket_id + '" class="ticket-id-class">' + d.short_title + '</span>',
                        postcode: d.postcode,
                        state: d.state,
                        customer: d.customer_name,
                        status: d.status,
                        priority: '<font color="' + d.color + '">' + d.priority + '</font>',
                        fault: d.fault_type,
                        category: d.category,
                        author: d.author_name,
                        owner: d.owner_name,
                        age: d.days_age,
                        lastupdate: d.update_date
                    });
                break;

                case('deferred'):
                    DeferredNum = DeferredNum + 1;
                    tblDataDeferred.push({
                        ticket: '<span id="' + d.ticket_id + '" class="ticket-id-class">' + d.short_title + '</span>',
                        postcode: d.postcode,
                        state: d.state,
                        customer: d.customer_name,
                        status: d.status,
                        priority: '<font color="' + d.color + '">' + d.priority + '</font>',
                        fault: d.fault_type,
                        category: d.category,
                        author: d.author_name,
                        owner: d.owner_name,
                        age: d.days_age,
                        lastupdate: d.update_date
                    });
                break;

                case('closed'):
                    ClosedNum = ClosedNum + 1;
                    tblDataClosed.push({
                        ticket: '<span id="' + d.ticket_id + '" class="ticket-id-class">' + d.short_title + '</span>',
                        postcode: d.postcode,
                        state: d.state,
                        customer: d.customer_name,
                        status: d.status,
                        priority: '<font color="' + d.color + '">' + d.priority + '</font>',
                        fault: d.fault_type,
                        category: d.category,
                        author: d.author_name,
                        owner: d.owner_name,
                        age: d.days_age,
                        lastupdate: d.update_date
                    });
                break;

                default:
            };

        });
        if(OpenNum > 0) {
            renderPartnerTicketsList(tblDataOpen, idOpen, true);
        } else {
            renderPartnerTicketsList(tblEmptyMsg, idOpen, true);
        };
        if(OnHoldNum > 0) {
            renderPartnerTicketsList(tblDataOnHold, idOnHold, true);
        } else {
            renderPartnerTicketsList(tblEmptyMsg, idOnHold, true);
        };
        if(DeferredNum > 0) {
            renderPartnerTicketsList(tblDataDeferred, idDeferred, true);
        } else {
            renderPartnerTicketsList(tblEmptyMsg, idDeferred, true);
        };
        if(ClosedNum > 0) {
            renderPartnerTicketsList(tblDataClosed, idClosed, true);
        } else {
            renderPartnerTicketsList(tblEmptyMsg, idClosed, true);
        };

        jQuery('a[href="#tab1c47048a"]').html('Open Tickets<span class="ticket-count">' + OpenNum + '</span>');
        jQuery('a[href="#tab281c055c"]').html('On Hold Tickets<span class="ticket-count">' + OnHoldNum + '</span>');
        jQuery('a[href="#tab328b0619"]').html('Deferred Tickets<span class="ticket-count">' + DeferredNum + '</span>');
        jQuery('a[href="#tab26b60552"]').html('Closed Tickets<span class="ticket-count">' + ClosedNum + '</span>');
    })
    .done(function() {
        jQuery("#loader").fadeOut("slow");
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        var sysError = textStatus + ", " + error;
        showPopupMsg(errorClass, logoutFlag, "There was an error retrieving your Support Tickets List.<br/>Page wll not load from this point and you will be returned to our home page...<br/>Error: " + sysError); 
    });
};

function renderPartnerTicketsList(tblData, id, initLoad) {

    // Set up data for DataTable plugin

    if (!initLoad) {
        var tbl = jQuery('#' + id).DataTable();
        tbl.clear();
        tbl.rows.add(tblData);
        tbl.draw();
        return;
    };

    // Bind DataTable plugin
    var tblHtml = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="' + id + '"><thead><tr>';
    tblHtml += '<th>Ticket</th>';
    tblHtml += '<th>Postcode</th>';
    tblHtml += '<th>State</th>';
    tblHtml += '<th>Customer</th>';
    tblHtml += '<th>Status</th>';
    tblHtml += '<th>Priority</th>';
    tblHtml += '<th>Fault</th>';
    tblHtml += '<th>Category</th>';
    tblHtml += '<th>Author</th>';
    tblHtml += '<th>Owner</th>';
    tblHtml += '<th>Age</th>';
    tblHtml += '<th>Last Update</th>';
    tblHtml += '</tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>';

    jQuery('#' + id + '-container').html(tblHtml);

    jQuery('#' + id).dataTable({
        data: tblData,
        columns: [
          { data: "ticket" },
          { data: "postcode" },
          { data: "state" },
          { data: "customer" },
          { data: "status" },
          { data: "priority" },
          { data: "fault" },
          { data: "category" },
          { data: "author" },
          { data: "owner" },
          { data: "age" },
          { data: "lastupdate" }
        ],
        pageLength: 25,
        order: [12, 'desc'],
        "scrollCollapse": false,
        "jQueryUI": true,
        responsive: true
    });
};
```

---

I am losing the values inside of the array in the code below once I pass it to a function. I am using jQuery DataTables in my page. I have no syntax error though, just the code fails due to empty array.

MAIN CODE:

```
        jQuery.each( data, function( i, d ) {
            tblDataOpen.push({
                ticket: '<span id="' + d.ticket_id + '" class="ticket-id-class">' + d.short_title + '</span>',
                postcode: d.postcode,
                state: d.state,
                customer: d.customer_name
            });

console.log(tblDataOpen);   // <=== SHOWS THE ARRAY AS EXPECTED

            renderPartnerTicketsList(tblDataOpen, 'open');
```

FUNCTION:

```
    function renderPartnerTicketsList(tblData, id) {

console.log(tblData);   // <=== SHOWS AN EMPTY OBJECT

        var tblHtml = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="' + id + '"><thead><tr>';
        tblHtml += '<th>Ticket</th>';
        tblHtml += '<th>Postcode</th>';
        tblHtml += '<th>State</th>';
        tblHtml += '<th>Customer</th>';
        tblHtml += '</tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>';

        jQuery('#' + id + '-container').html(tblHtml);

    console.log(tblData);

        jQuery('#' + id).dataTable({    
            data: tblData,
            columns: [
              { data: "ticket" },
              { data: "postcode" },
              { data: "state" },
              { data: "customer" }
            ],
            pageLength: 25,
            order: [3, 'desc'],
            "scrollCollapse": false,
            "jQueryUI": true,
            responsive: true
        });
    };
```

Comment: You pass the value to tblData, use tblData instead of tblDataOpen.

Comment: Sorry Alex G. I corrected my code above. I am using tblData in the function

Comment: Try passing a cloned copy - `$.extend(true, [], tblDataOpen);` to `renderPartnerTicketsList`

Comment: sounds like an asynch problem and you are trying to render the table outside of success callback of ajax. SHow more code

Comment: Is this the exact flow of your code? Have you literally copy-pasted the source? (what you describe is simply not possible).

Comment: @TheRealPapa Please don't change this question to a completely different one. Close this one, and open a new one with your new question.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in `renderPartnerTicketsList()` to make sure it's actually called from the place where you think it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code like this:

```
console.log(tblDataOpen);   // <=== SHOWS THE ARRAY AS EXPECTED

        renderPartnerTicketsList(tblDataOpen, 'open');
```

works. Really. Millions of people use it every day billions of times.

So that means the problem must be elsewhere. To debug the issue, you need to set a breakpoint in the function `renderPartnerTicketsList()` and then the browser stops, look at the call stack. My guess is that `renderPartnerTicketsList()` is called from other places as well.

Comment: Got it. I found the problem and it had (embarrassingly!) to do with the misspelling of an element id... this is what happens I guess after 12 hours straight and 10 energy drinks! I have closed the Q.